# loading the same image in multiple R sessions

Tags: multithreading, r, hadoop, parallel-processing, hpc

I have a set of firms that I want to process. Each firm takes a while to process so I would like to parallelize it. There are two questions I have:

1. can i load the same R workspace image (containing firm returns for example) in multiple instances of R and spit out the results to a csv file (appending) and thus explicitly parallelize things that way?
2. there must be better ways to do this. i looked around the HPC task view and I think things like MPI are a bit too complicated for this task? Any suggestions?

Here is the kind of thing I am thinking. This is vastly simplified but conveys the point quite clearly:

```
require(data.table)
dtb = data.table(data.frame(a=1:100, id=1:2), key="id")
save(dataf, file="mydata.RData")

#now launch a session that accepts the id argument
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
theid = as.integer(args[1])
load("mydata.RData")
r = dtb[id == theid,sum(a)]
write.csv(r, "myfile.csv", append=TRUE)
```

This would obviously work very fast but I am running lots of rolling regressions per firm so it's a bit slow but each process is independent.
Note that I would like to run this on an LSF grid with different nodes starting the sessions.  Currently I just submit several jobs with parameters. I would like a better way.

Comment: read the HPC task view a little more carefully, I think -- especially `parallel` (now a Recommended (i.e. built-in) package) and `foreach`.  And yes, you can do this.  Maybe you could provide a (small) reproducible example?

Comment: sure! i'll throw something together and add it